# Text getting cropped in cell C# gridview windows

Tags: c#

I am using a gridview in a C# windows application. One of the cells has a long string of text (see below) but whenever it is bound to the grid the cell gets cropped and the scrollbar [does not get to end of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwSqL.jpg) to display the full text. The scrollbar doesn't scroll smoothly when dragging with a mouse either.

I tried different combinations for `RowSize` and ColumnSize` modes, but with no luck.

```
void FillGrid()
{
    DataTable tasktable = new DataTable();
    tasktable.Columns.Add("Logged By", typeof(string));
    tasktable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    tasktable.Columns.Add("Notes", typeof(string));
    DataRow dr1;
    //for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    //{
    dr1 = tasktable.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = "Sunit Shah";
    dr1[1] = System.DateTime.Now;
    dr1[2] = "Test Note";
    tasktable.Rows.Add(dr1);
    //}
    dr1 = tasktable.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = "Sunit Shah";
    dr1[1] = System.DateTime.Now;
    dr1[2] = "Test Note";
    dr1[2] = "Paul Pogba will have a medical at Manchester United on Monday after 
            Juventus granted permission for him to seal a potential world record 
            transfer.Juventus manager Massimo Allegri refused to be drawn further
            on the transfer when he was asked about it in his post-match press 
            conference following a friendly against West Ham at the London Stadium,
            but an official at the Italian club confirmed they had authorised the 
            midfielder to have United doctors assess him ahead of the move. 
            Allegri merely said: ‘I spoke about Pogba the day before, we have 
            just finished a match and I don’t know much more, we will see on Monday 
            if he is a still Juventus player.’";

    tasktable.Rows.Add(dr1);
    DataTable fillNotesGrid = new DataTable();
    fillNotesGrid = (from row in tasktable.AsEnumerable()
                     orderby row.Field<DateTime>("Date") descending
                     select row).CopyToDataTable();
    dgvSIDetailsNotes.DataSource = fillNotesGrid;    
}
```

Comment: Are you able to post the code you're using to display the grid?

Comment: I have just now added

Comment: I would consider why you would display said text in a gridview in the first place. It might be better to show it outside of the grid in its own text box, which changes when you select a different row.

Comment: There are many notes which I am showing in gridview and not large enough. Only few are very large which is causing this issue.

Comment: @Interminable Are you able to help on this ?

Comment: @Hemil I think so!  Have a look at my answer and see if what it proposes works for you.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: I'll admit that I guessed it was WinForms based on the screenshot.  I didn't want to update the tags in case that guess was wrong.  Correct tagging helps people to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, it looks like your problem isn't that it's truncating the data, it's that it's snapping to cells when you scroll, so it's right at the top of every cell when you scroll.  If it's it's too big for the space available, you'll only see as much of the top part of that row as you can fit.  Basically, it behaves like Microsoft Excel.

I don't think there's a way to turn off this behaviour in the standard `DataGridView` control.

HOWEVER, as a workaround you can add your `DataGridView` to a `System.Windows.Forms.Panel`, and make the `Panel` do your scrolling for you!

Simply make the `DataGridView` a child of the `Panel` control, and set the `Panel`'s `AutoScroll` property to `true` and the `DataGridView`'s `AutoSize` property to `true` and that should do the trick.

**EDIT**

I have included some source code to try and make things clear.

This is source code from the form (with the body of `FillGrid()`) omitted as it's identical to the source code in your question).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True; //I'm assuming this is already set in your own source code as the cell is wrapping its text in your screenshot.
        panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSize = true;

        FillGrid();
    }

    void FillGrid()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is how the controls are created in `Form1.Designer.cs`:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
```

This is the generated `InitializeComponent()` method in the Designer.

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(145, 122);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 126);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

This should be everything you need to replicate this solution in a test project.

If you're experiencing issues with this in your main project then you may have other code that is interfering.

Comment: We have tried it. But It's not working.
We have added a panel and kept its AutoScroll property to True
Kept Data Gridview Scrollbars to None
And kept Autosize to true at runtime. 
Still same behaviour. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Hemil I have updated the Answer to include some source code that should help you.  If you continue to experience issues, you will have to provide further information on exactly what it is you're doing, what you're working with, etc.